# powershell select all objects from type Directory

Tags: powershell

i try to write a script, that checks all Directories in a root Directory, is there a way to only select objects from datatype "Directory"?

i tried to store all the directories into an array, but this dont worked for me.

if i could store all Directory names inside the root Directory this would help me a lot.

*What i done before:*

create a list that stores all directory names:

`$sidepaths = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]`

i tried to select all directories with `-ItemType Directory` but this dont worked for me.

Comment: `$sidepaths = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\rootDirectory' -Directory`

Comment: Follow @Theo's advice (and maybe add the `-Recurse` parameter to store _**all** the directories_)?

Answer (score 0):

like @Theo said:

```sh
$sidepaths = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\rootDirectory' -Directory
```